# can we make an ios app using unity 3D with xcode4?

Tags: ios5, xcode4, unity-game-engine

Is there any SDK available for Unity 3D for making an ios game .I am new to this unity 3D,I have found many things while searching as download unity development tool then we can make apps which can run on both Windows and Mac.

My doubts are
1.How we can make an unity 3D app using xcode?
2.Can we use objective c code?(I got informations like we can only use javascript/c# for mobile app development in unity 3D)

Please help me...
thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not go to the Unity site and read up. Then report back and answer your question here.

Comment: Agree w/ skinnyTod and you should accept Jessy's answer below, Unity very explicitly states how it handles apps.

Answer (score 2):

http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses